# Script SQL constraint for a number to fall within a Range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

How to script a constraint on a field in a table, for an acceptable range of values is between 0 and 100?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE Table
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Table_Column_Range CHECK (
   Column >= 0 AND Column <= 100 --Inclusive
)
```

Comment: If you use `BETWEEN 0 AND 100` as mentioned in other answers, SQL Server Management Studio will convert it to `([column]>=(0) AND [column]<=(100))` for you if you're using the GUI to create it.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE myTableName
ADD CONSTRAINT myTableName_myColumnName_valZeroToOneHundred
CHECK (myColumnName BETWEEN 0 AND 100)
```

This check would be inclusive - here is some info about BETWEEN from MSDN:
[BETWEEN (Transact SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922(SQL.90).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

A check constraint like "fieldname BETWEEN 0 AND 100" should do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, the right question isn't "how" but "why".

This 0-100 rule sounds to me like a business rule. Why should it be implemented on the server/database side? If an incorrect value is entered, who will get the error message?

If the user gets the error message, wouldn't it be easier to have the code giving him the message before the transaction reaches the server?

What about range modification? May the rule change? I guess yes: rules ALLWAYS change. Can the range be updated from 0-100 to 101-200? In this case, what about values already entered in the database?

Comment: @Phillippe Grondier: You would be surprised to see the incredible amount of bad data sitting on database servers of medium and large organizations, due to silly human errors or sometimes convoluted system errors difficult to figure out or reproduce. The more innovation you have in a business, the greater the chance of injecting bad data into databases. If you are willing to have a consistent database, just implement the necessary checks right into the database schema. What happens if the user receives an error message? Many things, except inserting bad data into the database.

Comment: @Philippe Grondier: If the rule changes, then update the constraint.  If values already in the database no longer fit within the range that would be handled during the data migrations to the new schema.

Comment: a 0-100 check constraint is a data validation rule. Data validation is one of the key factors in using an RDBMS. If you don't have any validation or integrity checks within the RDBMS, expect inconsistent or inadequate data validation across applications; application errors when your DB disseminates invalid data; "Sherlock Holmsing" from where mysterious invalid data came; angry end-users, angrier senior managers, emergencies, firefighting, and 6am Sunday wake-up calls.