# Set a value within a range 0-30

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to set a value which is allowed to be between 0 and 30. I am working in the desing mode in MSSQL.

Comment: Set a value for what??  Please be more specific and give your use-case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I script SQL constraint for a number to fall within a range?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382108/how-do-i-script-sql-constraint-for-a-number-to-fall-within-a-range)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a check constraint with the following definition

```
YourColumn BETWEEN 0 AND 30
```

In TSQL you would do this by

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable 
    ADD YourColumn TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT CK_Name CHECK (YourColumn BETWEEN 0 AND 30)
```

In SSMS table designer you need to right click and choose "Check Constraints" from the short cut menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tinyint (Integer data from 0 through 255. Storage size is 1 byte.) is the smallest in sql server, and in your application you create a business code to accept only the range that you want.